# Non subdomain is "not private" but subdomain is

Tags: apache2, cloudflare, ubuntu, linode

I am trying to setup a website for my app domain using an Ubuntu/Apache server hosted on Linode and Cloudflare.

The setup works for

`www.my.app`

but not for just

`my.app` without the www.

My settings are as follows:

## Cloudflare Crypto

- SSL - `Full (strict)`
- Edge Certificates

  - `my.app`, `*.my.app`
  - Type `Universal`
  - 1 `SHA 2 ECDSA` Certificate
- Origin Certificates

  - `my.app`, `*.my.app`
- Universal SSL is not disabled

## my.app.conf Apache File

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/my.app.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/my.app.key

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin just@thisguy.com
  ServerName www.my.app
  ServerAlias my.app

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/myapp/code/myapp/public/
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/myapp/code/myapp/storage/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /home/myapp/code/myapp/storage/logs/access.log combined

  <Directory /home/myapp/code/myapp/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I read elsewhere that `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` can be important and I have tried swapping these values and restarting apache without success.

## Browser Error Screenshots

[image: Not private Chrome]
[image: Not private Safari]

## Certs

The certs appear to be different, I'm not sure how this is possible, but clearly there is something in the config on my server.

[image]